# How can i format turkish lira with symbol?

Tags: java, formatting, locale

I tried to do it with the locale, but it only appears as text and the symbol doesn't come out. I am using JAVA 14 SDK.

Code I tried:

```
  Locale tr = new Locale("tr", "TR");
  BigDecimal points = new BigDecimal(175678.64);
  System.out.println(NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(tr).format(points));
```

Output:

```
175.678,64 TL
```

I want:

```
₺175.678,64
```

Comment: I also tried (on my locale, with java 14(win)), but (besides it cannot print "₺" `\u20BA`) i get `?175.678,64` (so another "default format") ...modifying the currency symbol (https://kodejava.org/how-do-i-change-the-currency-symbol/) had no effect ...and i also asserted it equal (to `\u20BA` before modification).

Comment: That code produces `₺175.678,64` for me, while running in the en-US locale.  What does `System.out.println(Locale.getDefault());` display?

Comment: By the way, you should pass your input number as text (add quote marks). Otherwise you are defeating the purpose of using `BigDecimal`.

Comment: @VGR I don't want to do this with default, because we don't know what is the default value everyone's computer.

Comment: That makes sense, but I have to wonder if perhaps your default locale is the problem.

Comment: Try `Locale tr = Locale.forLanguageTag("tr-TR-u-cu-try");` instead.  If that doesn’t work, try `Locale tr = Locale.forLanguageTag("tr-TR-u-rg-trzzzz");`.  The first overrides the locale’s currency designation;  the second overrides the locale’s regional settings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## No problem

I broke out your code to multiple lines for easier debugging.

When I [run it in the IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/h5GyUe) site, I get your desired output.

By the way, you should pass your input number as text (add quote marks). Otherwise you are defeating the purpose of using BigDecimal.

```
/* package whatever; // don't place package name! */

import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

import java.math.* ;
import java.text.* ;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        // your code goes here

Locale locale = new Locale("tr", "TR");
  BigDecimal points = new BigDecimal( "175678.64" ) ;


NumberFormat f = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance( locale ) ;
String output = f.format( points ) ;

System.out.println( output ) ;


    }
}
```

When run:

> ₺175.678,64

Comment: Yes, you're right. It's my fault. I got an error message from something else. Thank you for your help. :D

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the `Currency` class of `java.util.Currency`. 
The `Currency` class has two methods `getSymbol()` and `getSymbol(Locale locale)`. In your case you should use the second method with the `locale` parameter. This will return a `String` that represents the currency symbol for turkish lira.

You can initialize your `Currency` object like this:

```java
Currency currency = Currency.getInstance(tr);
```

and

```java
currency.getSymbol(tr);
```

will return the currency symbol as a `String`

In addition, you should know that the unidoce representation of turkish lira symbol as a char in Java is `\u20BA`

Answer (score 0):

try this  change 'Locale.CANADA' with your country

```
NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.CANADA);
        String currency = format.format(number);
        System.out.println("Currency in Canada : " + currency);
```

Comment: My code is the same as your code, and my country doesn't have a locale code.

Comment: http://www.localeplanet.com/java/tr-TR/index.html
i think that the library locale has only this symbol it's better to check if there's another library for currency symbols in java